# Check if another user placed bid on auction Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a function that checks if user is following auction:

```
public function checked($auctionId)
{
    return $this->bidCheck()->where('product_id', $auctionId)->count() > 0;
}
```

How to make a function that will check if another user is placed bid on the auction that user is following ?

Comment: post your db structure

Comment: `bid_checks` table storing: `user_id` and `product_id` @Gal

Comment: you'ill need to add a date column to your table

Comment: @Gal It is. It's called `created_at`

Comment: I guess the easiest solution would be to attach it to `bid created` event,once a user creates a bid check who has the biggest bid and notify to that user that his bid has been over-bidden if this is the first bid then don't do anything

Comment: Yeah, but I don't know how to exactly write that sentence.

Comment: which part ? the event part is built in laravel - [eloquent events](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#events) and for the query you'ill need to post your bid model

Comment: I don't know how to check if another user placed bigger bid than the other. @Gal

Comment: you have `created` event of the eloquent,just add there a code that will send notification to all the auction followers

Comment: I need to add that code to User.php ?

Comment: @Gal Help, I have never used in my life `events`

Comment: I gave you a link that explains well how to use it - https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#events you can also do it yourself by adding the code directly into your store method but it would make it a bit messy